# Getting selectbox values on submit

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

In my application i have 3 tables user, userprofile and department.

**User Table :**

- User_Id
- User_Type
- User_Pswd

**UserProfile Table :**

- Profile_Id
- Profile_UserId (Foreign key linked to user table)
- User_Name
- Deapartment_Id (Foreign key linked to department table)

**Department Table :**

- Dpt_Id
- Dpt_Name

SelectBox for department in jsp is :

```
<p>
    <label for="dropdown">Department: </label>
    <form:select path="department" cssClass="dropdown">
       <form:option value="">Select Department</form:option>
       <c:if test="${fn:length(departList) > 0}">
          <c:forEach items="${departList}" var="depart" varStatus="status">
              <c:if test="${status.count % 2 == 0}">even</c:if>
                 <form:option value="${depart.departmentId}">${depart.departmentName}/form:option>
          </c:forEach>
       </c:if>
    </form:select>
</p>
```

And in controller i am getting Userprofile bean's object.

Now my question is in the submit method in controller how can i get the department bean as bound to the values i used to set in jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) to convert the ids to the real objects.
This converter must be registered with the FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.

@see [Spring Reference Chapter Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)